# I keep getting an error when i use else in python

Tags: python

I've looked as much as I can, and tried even more than that; I keep
getting a message that says syntax error invalid syntax else:
                                                           ^

```
import random
import sys
import os
engine1 = 100


print('--------------------------Welcome-----------------------')

code = input('please enter your code')
type(code)
if code in['2476']:
    print('thank you')
    setup = input('what is your next code')
    type(setup)
else:
break
```

Comment: You need to indent in the else block as well.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Why do you have an `else:` then? Just remove the `else:`. And remove the `break`, because that's only valid inside a loop, and there is no loop here.

Comment: Also, what is `if code in['2576']:` supposed to test? That's not a valid Python expression either. The `type(code)` and `type(setup)` expressions don't achieve anything, they could be removed as well.

Comment: I indented the else and still get the error code

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sure it's a valid Python expression. You don't need a space between `in` and its argument if the argument starts with a delimiter, so it means the same thing as `code in ['2746']`. And it's even a meaningful test, although one that could be written more simply as `code == '2746'`.

Comment: @abarnert: ick, of course. `in` is a keyword, so it'd never be parsed as a variable name, and by extension, the `[...]` is not an indexing operation. Bedtime, clearly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Actually, that doesn't apply to all keywords—e.g., `None[2]` and `True[2]` are indexing operations (that are guaranteed to raise `AttributeError`). I think if you went through the keywords carefully one by one and tried to guess whether they'd parse this as indexing, as a list display, or as a syntax error, even a relatively new Python developer would guess them all right (although, IIRC, `lambda` is a syntax error via a different path than you'd expect), but they'd also probably throw up in their mouths a little doing so…

Comment: Why break here? What you want to do with else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, python uses indentation instead of brackets to designate scope. This means that the body of an `if` or `else` or `while` block must be indented one level. The first problem with your code is that the line `break` after your `else:` statement is not indented. This is a problem and will cause a syntax error.

The second problem with your code, which you will find when you indent the `break` command, is that you're not using `break` correctly. Honestly I don't know *why* you're using `break` here, but the purpose of the `break` command is to break out of a loop - a *for* or *while* block. If you're not in a loop - and an `if`/`else` is not a loop - it doesn't do anything. I don't know why you even have an `else` statement. If you want to quit the program in the `else` block, you can use

```
sys.exit()
```

to kill the program. Or you can just let it run out of code, which will also work. In this code snippet, you could remove the `else` entirely and it would work the exact same.

Comment: thanks, this helped. i'm used to php so i check the project before it's finished which set me up for failure.